# Visual Studio 2015 (Asp.net 5) Test Explorer not showing test cases

Tags: .net

My Test Explorer was working for a short period for XUnit Testing for VNext projects.  Suddenly it stopped working.  Under the out of test I see this message

```
------ Discover test started ------
Unable to find the kre installation directory for the source: 'F:\cv\corvette-common-netlib\DotNet\src\Tests\ECS.Common.Tests\project.json'
========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:00.1850106) ==========
```

As I understand Aspnet 5.0 is now using kvm instead of kre, test explorer does not show up tests case might be cause of this error.  I'm not sure how to resolve this

Comment: Met the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio check that your test settings default's architecture is the same than your default dnx runtime.

You can configure it under : **Test** > **Test Setting** > **Default Processor Architecture**.

Comment: I go to Test > Test Setting > Default Processor Architecture and switch back and forth 32bit and 64 bit and hit 'Run All'. Nothing changes

Comment: Ok, it still seem like there is a missmatch between your runtime (DNX) version and the dependencies you add to your projects. Witch version of Mvc/Xunit runner are you referencing and what's your current DNX version ?
You should try to install DNVM and upgrade to last version (and same for your dependencies) as described here : https://github.com/aspnet/home